# Insert into Table2 the primary key ID that belongs to a selected value from a table1

Tags: sql, wpf

In my wpf application, I want to insert the ID associated with a selected value (Name in dropdown list) into another table. e.g. Select Michael from the list. Michaels PK is 1. When I click on an Add Button 1 becomes the fk in another table that will link Michaels address details.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table2 (fkID) SELECT DISTINCT ID from Table1 where ID =('" + cbName.Text + "')", sc);;
```

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: You might want to use a profiler to see exaclty what is being sent to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you may want to supply some more information so the good people here can attempt an answer.

To insert all of the foreign keys from Table2 into another table, say Table1
you may be looking for SQL something like

INSERT INTO Table2 (ForeignKeyID) SELECT DISTINCT ForeignKeyID FROM Table1 WHERE SomeIDField = 'SomeValue' ?

Comment: Thanks, your syntax runs but no entry inserted. My 'someValue' comes from a dropdown list of Names.